# How do I insert a string with a back slash into a table using C#

Tags: c#, database, string, replace

I'm new to C#, am still teaching myself it and am coming from Visual FoxPro programming. The problem I have is I want to insert a value from a textbox in a form that only contains computer directories. In that field I select C:\ and when I run the code I get the error: *Incorrect syntax near 'C:'*.

The field name that contains the directory value is `lblVault` and is a label object.

The code I run looks like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;" +
    "AttachDbFilename=C:\\Development\\C-Sharp\\LockItUp\\Lockitup.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    string stmt = "INSERT INTO Users(username,password,folderloc,fullname,email,cellphone) " +
    "VALUES (" + @txtUsrName.Text + "," + @txtUserPassword.Text + "," + @lblVault.Text + "," +
        @txtFullname.Text + "," + @txtEmail.Text + "," + @txtCellPhone.Text + ")";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, connect))
    {
        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unless you are doing a ASP.NET website `AttachDbFilename` is almost never the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 3):

Easiest and safest way (google "SQL injection") is use parameters even with SQL queries. Not just it would take care of formatting strings for you, but also save you from simplest security problems.

```
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;" +
            "AttachDbFilename=C:\\Development\\C-Sharp\\LockItUp\\Lockitup.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                string stmt = "INSERT INTO Users(username,password,folderloc,fullname,email,cellphone) " +
                "VALUES (@username,@password,@folderloc,@fullname,@email,@cellphone)";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(stmt, connect))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username",txtUsrName.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", txtUserPassword.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@folderloc",lblVault.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@fullname", txtFullname.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@email",txtEmail.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@cellphone",txtCellPhone.Text);
                    try
                    {
                        connect.Open();
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        connect.Close();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to how your connection string has extra slashes in it, you need extra slashes in your concatenated string to let C# understand the difference between a slash char, and a slash meant to escape into a different char. (For example \n means new line.)

```
@lblVault.Text.Replace(@"\", @"\\")
```

or

```
@lblVault.Text.Replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

The @ symbol means don't allow any escaping. Slash means slash and only slash.